# Flutter mask a circle into a container

Tags: android, flutter, skia

I want to add a circle effect over a container, but I want the circle to not extend the dimensions of the container, but instead get clipped by it. This is what I'm trying to achieve:
[image]

As you can see the white circle naturally would extend the red container but instead, I'm trying to make it stay into the borders. How can I do it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to using an overlap and cliprect.

```
class OverlapSquare extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 200,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
      child: ClipRect(
        clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
        child: OverflowBox(
          maxHeight: 250,
          maxWidth: 250,
          child: Center(
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The OverFlowBox allows the circle to draw outside the bounds of its parent, and then the cliprect cuts it back to the edge.

Just an FYI - on my device I'm getting a tiny red line at the top & bottom of the white circle. I'm fairly sure that's a recently-introduced bug in flutter as I'm also seeing something similar if I put a white border around the container. I've raised [an issue on github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25009) for that.

Comment: that worked! Thank you!!, but just as a sidenote. If I do not have the size to put into the maxHeight and maxWidth but I wanted to costraint them to the size of the parent, how could I do?

Comment: Sorry - I don't quite understand. If you want it to be the size of the parent, you don't need the clipping do you? That being said, look at [LayoutBuilder](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html) as it might be what you're looking for.

Comment: If I need the  white container to be centered on the left how could I do?

Comment: Instead of using Center, you should be able to use Align with the appropriate alignment set.

Answer (score 7):

ClipRRect worked best for me.

See reference video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eI43jkQkrvs&vl=en

```
ClipRRect(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.cirular(10),
  child: myContainerWithCircleWidget,
);
```