# Make Widgets bigger than Viewport?

Tags: flutter, dart

In my flutter application, I would like to make a circle as a background like that: [image: ViewPort]

Comment: Nice idea. What's keeping you from doing it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter mask a circle into a container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53639066/flutter-mask-a-circle-into-a-container)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is mainly when the screen is in landscape, you can't fit a circle there unless it covers all the screen.
There's another approach with ClipRect, let me know if this doesn't work with you.

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) {
        final radius = constraints.biggest.width * 1.2;
        
        return SizedBox(
          width: radius,
          height: radius,
          child: FittedBox(
            fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
            child: Container(
              width: radius,
              height: radius ,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Another approach:

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) {
        final radius = constraints.biggest.width * 1.2;
        
        return OverflowBox(
          maxWidth: radius,
          maxHeight: radius,
          child: Container(
            width: radius,
            height: radius ,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    );
  }
}
```

`final radius = constraints.biggest.width * 1.2;`:
The `1.2` is how much the circle is overlapping, you can change this number.