# Can I overflow a widget in Container to make it like clipped?

Tags: flutter

I'm following the picture below but got some difficulties when I tried to make that white bubble.

[image]

I have tried a method using `OverFlowBox` from another post [Flutter mask a circle into a container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53639066/flutter-mask-a-circle-into-a-container) but I got the circle stuck in the middle of the `Container` and I don't know why `alignment` won't help moving it. Here is what I've tried:

```
return Container(
  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
  height: screenHeight/3.5,
  width: screenWidth/3.5,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
      topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
      topRight: Radius.circular(60),
      bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10),
      bottomRight: Radius.circular(10),
    ),
    gradient: LinearGradient(
      begin: FractionalOffset.topLeft,
      end: FractionalOffset.bottomRight,
      colors: [boxColorBegin, boxColorEnd]
    ),
  ),
  child: ClipRect(
    clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
    child: OverflowBox(
      maxHeight: screenHeight/3.5 +20,
      maxWidth: screenWidth/3.5 + 20,
      child:Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
        ),
      )
    ),
  ),
);
```

And the result was

[image]

Is there any ways to overflow something inside a widget so that it looks like clipped?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if you want some widget to overflow it's parent why do you use clip then?

Comment: cos I actually want the overflowed part to be clipped

Comment: but if you want just to position your child you dont need `OverflowBox` at all: `child: Container(
  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
  clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
    color: Colors.grey,
  ),
  child: FractionalTranslation(
    translation: Offset(-0.25, -0.5),
    child: Container(
      width: 200,
      height: 200,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.orange,
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
      ),
    ),
  ),
),`

Comment: I seeee so you can use `Container` for clipping. I think your code is the simplest one without extra `Stack`, `ClipRRect` or duplicating `BorderRadius`. Do you want to leave an answer?

Comment: "Do you want to leave an answer? " just edit your self answer and add alternate solution with `clipBehavior` and `FractionalTranslation`

Comment: Alright. Thanks!

Comment: sure, your welcome, btw you could avoid `FractionalTranslation` too and instead of `Alignment.topLeft` use `Alignment(-1, -2)` or something but when using `FractionalTranslation` you have more precise control on how to position the child widget

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the way to achieve what I want but am still confused why `OverFlowBox` can't be aligned. I thought it is because the size of the `OverFlowBox` is larger than its parent but it still don't work when I changed it to a smaller size.

I used `Stack` and `Positioned` widget and set the `overflow` parameter of the Stack as `overflow.clip`

Here is the code:

```
return Container(
  height: screenHeight/3.5,
  width: screenWidth/3.2,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
      topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
      topRight: Radius.circular(60),
      bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10),
      bottomRight: Radius.circular(10),
    ),
    gradient: LinearGradient(
      begin: FractionalOffset.topLeft,
      end: FractionalOffset.bottomRight,
      colors: [boxColorBegin, boxColorEnd]
    ),
  ),
  child: Stack(
    overflow: Overflow.clip,
    alignment: Alignment.topCenter ,
    children: <Widget>[
      Positioned(
        bottom: screenHeight / 8,
        right: screenWidth / 12,
        child: Container(
          width: screenWidth / 3.5,
          height: screenHeight / 3.5,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white38,
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
          ),
        )
      )
    ],
  )
)
```

And the result is

[image]

**EDIT**

Turns out you can just use `Container` as a clipper with the `clipBehavior` parameter and use `FractionalTranslation` widget as child to manipulate the position of the white circle. Thanks to [pskink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63533364/can-i-overflow-a-widget-in-container-to-make-it-like-clipped/63533560#comment112346774_63533364) for the simple answer.

Here is the new code

```
return Container(
  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
  clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
  height: screenHeight/3.5,
  width: screenWidth/3.2,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
      topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
      topRight: Radius.circular(60),
      bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10),
      bottomRight: Radius.circular(10),
    ),
    gradient: LinearGradient(
      begin: FractionalOffset.topLeft,
      end: FractionalOffset.bottomRight,
      colors: [boxColorBegin, boxColorEnd]
    ),
  ),
  child: FractionalTranslation(
    translation: Offset(-0.25, -0.5),
    child: Container(
      width: screenWidth / 3.5,
      height: screenHeight / 3.5,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white38,
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
      ),
    )
  )
);
```

Comment: I wish I could give you 3 upvotes

Comment: i don't get why did you put `Stack.overflow` there. i thought it's because you're get carried away from the site name :D can you please correct it because there's no `Stack.overflow` property in flutter?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily accomplish this using ClipRRect as your root container for this widget. Provide it a border radius and it will clip all children and prevent them from painting outside the bounds. You can then use Transform.translate to render a circle and offset it outside its parent.

[I created a sample pen for you to try](https://codepen.io/nkshah2/pen/LYNbajG)

```
return ClipRRect(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
    topLeft: Radius.circular(8),
    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(8),
    bottomRight: Radius.circular(8),
    topRight: Radius.circular(125),
  ),
  child: Container(
    height: 400,
    width: 250,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.red,
    ),
    child: Stack(
      children: [
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
          child: Transform.translate(
            offset: Offset(-40, -100),
            child: Container(
              height: 220,
              width: 220,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(110)),
                color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.4),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

For more information on [ClipRRect](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ClipRRect-class.html) and [Transform.translate](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Transform/Transform.translate.html) visit the API docs.

Answer (score 0):

you can use padding to move the `OverflowBox`. you also need to clip the parent `Container` with `ClipRRect`

**here is your fix (tested and works):**

```dart
return ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
            topRight: Radius.circular(60),
            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10),
            bottomRight: Radius.circular(10),
          ),
          child: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            height: screenHeight / 3.5,
            width: screenWidth / 3.5,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                topRight: Radius.circular(60),
                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(10),
              ),
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                  begin: FractionalOffset.topLeft, end: FractionalOffset.bottomRight, colors: [boxColorBegin, boxColorEnd]),
            ),
            child: ClipRect(
              clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 130, bottom: 150),
                child: OverflowBox(
                    maxHeight: screenHeight / 3.5 + 20,
                    maxWidth: screenWidth / 3.5 + 20,
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white.withAlpha(80),
                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      ),
                    )),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but may I know why wrapping the Container with ClipRRect is necessary? and why the OverFlowBox cannot be aligned?

Comment: so that the white circle won't be drawn outside the box. just remove the ClipRRect and see